# Matter.js collision not detecting after setting velocity

Tags: javascript, processing, collision, p5.js, matter.js

```js
var Engine = Matter.Engine,
  World = Matter.World,
  Bodies = Matter.Bodies,
  Body = Matter.Body;
  
var ground;
var engine;
var player = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  engine = Engine.create();
  world = engine.world;
  Engine.run(engine)
  var options = {
    isStatic: true
  }
  engine.world.gravity.y = 0
  my = new Cell(200, 200, 32)
  ground = Bodies.rectangle(200, height, width, 20, options)
  World.add(world, ground)

  //  engine.world.gravity.y = 0;
  console.log(player)
}

function keyPressed() {
  player.push(new Cell(mouseX, mouseY, 32));
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  my.show();
  for (var i = 0; i < player.length; i++) {
    player[i].show();
  }
}

function Cell(x, y, r) {
  this.body = Matter.Bodies.circle(x, y, r, r);
  //   World.add(world,this.body);
  this.r = r;
  World.add(world, this.body)
  //  player[player.length] = this;
  this.show = function() {
    var pos = this.body.position;
    Body.setVelocity(this.body, {
      x: mouseX - pos.x,
      y: mouseY - pos.y
    })
    push();
    translate(pos.x, pos.y)
    //  noStroke()
    ellipseMode(CENTER);
    ellipse(0, 0, this.r * 2, this.r * 2)
    pop();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.12.0/matter.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/p5.min.js"></script>
```

If I comment out `Body.setVelocity`, then collision works fine but not when using `Body.setVelocity`. Code above is working, please help me with broken collision detection. You can check collision problem by pressing keys more than 4 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit unclear what you try to achieve. But the code

> ```
> Body.setVelocity(this.body, {
>       x: mouseX - pos.x,
>       y: mouseY - pos.y
>   })
> ```

in `show`, sets a velocity to the body, which is equal the distance of the mouse position to the body, repeatedly in every frame. This causes that each body moves too the mouse position immediately and breaks down the collision detection.

You have to modify the actual velocity of the body, by a certain value, witch depends on the distance of the bod to the mouse position. e.g.:

```js
vx = this.body.velocity.x + (mouseX - pos.x) * 0.001
vy = this.body.velocity.y + (mouseY - pos.y) * 0.001
Body.setVelocity(this.body, {x: vx, y: vy } )
```

```js
var Engine = Matter.Engine,
  World = Matter.World,
  Bodies = Matter.Bodies,
  Body = Matter.Body;
  
var ground;
var engine;
var player = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  engine = Engine.create();
  world = engine.world;
  Engine.run(engine)
  var options = {
    isStatic: true
  }
  engine.world.gravity.y = 0
  my = new Cell(200, 200, 32)
  ground = Bodies.rectangle(200, height, width, 20, options)
  World.add(world, ground)

  //  engine.world.gravity.y = 0;
  console.log(player)
}

function keyPressed() {
  player.push(new Cell(mouseX, mouseY, 32));
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  my.show();
  for (var i = 0; i < player.length; i++) {
    player[i].show();
  }
}

function Cell(x, y, r) {
  this.body = Matter.Bodies.circle(x, y, r, r);
  //   World.add(world,this.body);
  this.r = r;
  World.add(world, this.body)
  //  player[player.length] = this;
  this.show = function() {
    var pos = this.body.position;
    
    vx = this.body.velocity.x + (mouseX - pos.x) * 0.001
    vy = this.body.velocity.y + (mouseY - pos.y) * 0.001
    Body.setVelocity(this.body, {x: vx, y: vy } )
    
    push();
    translate(pos.x, pos.y)
    //  noStroke()
    ellipseMode(CENTER);
    ellipse(0, 0, this.r * 2, this.r * 2)
    pop();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.12.0/matter.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/p5.min.js"></script>
```